# Как настроить на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

У меня есть сайт на WordPress и он мне выводит записи, я вот хочу чтобы каждая карточка выводилась разным цветом в зависимости от её тарифа, а так же при поиске, по фильтрам нужно сортировать и некоторые тарифы должны быть первыми. В какой файл мне нужно рыть это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Никто не знает что у тебя есть "карточки" и "тарифы". В ВП нет таких сущностей Исправь вопрос